# Calculte confidence interval

Tags: economics, confidence-interval

Suppose in 2011 a survey of 1038 workers in the city of Vancouver found that 221 used public transport to commute to work. Give your answers to the following to two decimal places.

Find a 95% confidence interval for the percentage of workers in Vancouver using public transport to commute to work. Use the sample proportion in your estimate of the standard error. Provide the upper and lower bounds for your confidence interval. (  ,  )

[This is what I came up with and need someone to correct me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9iLv.jpg)

Comment: your answer seems fine to me.